# Dailymotion URL not containing id

Tags: dailymotion-api

I have a Dailymotion URL with this format

```
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/ksjGDITdbTBhEpaC9qq
```

which correctly redirects to the video.

The part after `/video/` usually contains the ID of the video, but not in that particular case.

How can I retrieve data about that video from the Dailymotion API while having this kind of URL ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a video id, have you tried a normal API call?

https://api.dailymotion.com/video/ksjGDITdbTBhEpaC9qq

this will give you the data you want

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here is my API call, which is not working : 
https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=id,thumbnail_120_url,title,url&limit=100&ids=ksjGDITdbTBhEpaC9qq

I might have multiple IDs so I am using this endpoint